# Overloading member operator,?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Matrix;

struct literal_assignment_helper
{
    mutable int r;
    mutable int c;
    Matrix& matrix;

    explicit literal_assignment_helper(Matrix& matrix)
            : matrix(matrix), r(0), c(1) {}

    const literal_assignment_helper& operator,(int number) const;
};

struct Matrix
{
    int rows;
    int columns;
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    Matrix(int rows, int columns)
        : rows(rows), columns(columns), numbers(rows * columns) {}

    literal_assignment_helper operator=(int number)
    {
        numbers[0] = number;
        return literal_assignment_helper(*this);
    }

    int* operator[](int row) { return &numbers[row * columns]; }
};

const literal_assignment_helper& literal_assignment_helper::operator,(int number) const
{
    matrix[r][c] = number;

    c++;
    if (c == matrix.columns)
        r++, c = 0;

    return *this;
};


int main()
{
    int rows = 3, columns = 3;

    Matrix m(rows, columns);
    m = 1, 2, 3,
        4, 5, 6,
        7, 8, 9;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            std::cout << m[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This code is inspired by the [matrix class](http://dlib.net/dlib/matrix/matrix.h.html) in the [DLib](http://dlib.net/) library.

This code allows for assigning literal values separated by commas like this:

```
Matrix m(rows, columns);
m = 1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9;
```

Note that you can't do something like this:

```
Matrix m = 1, 2, 3, ...
```

This is because the constructor can't return a reference to another object, unlike the `operator=`.

Here in this code, if `literal_assignment_helper::operator,` is not const, this chaining of numbers doesn't work, the comma-separated numbers are considered to be comma-separated expressions.

Why must the operator be const? What are the rules here?

Also, what is the impact of an `operator,` that is not const? Is it ever going to be called?

Comment: Well, a method has to be `const` to be called on const objects. And `,` returns by a const reference. If you want to make `,` non-const, return by non-const reference.

Comment: [Demo with non-const](https://godbolt.org/z/o98vanoTh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const literal_assignment_helper& operator,(int number) const;
```

The comma operators, both in the helper and in the Matrix, return a const reference. So to call a member on that reference, the member function/operator has to be const qualified.

If you remove all the constness, like

```
literal_assignment_helper& operator,(int number);
```

that also seems to work.